# Is there a way to control the nuxt cache when deploying?

Tags: web, vue.js, deployment, nuxt.js

When using Nuxt, I ask questions.

When I distributed the site I built, the cache problem caused it to malfunction.
There are two cases below. Is there any way to solve them?

1. If built, the file names of js and css will be renamed to hash values, but it was not reflected by viewing old cache in browser.
2. Create applications using vue-native webview The webview in the application looked up the old cache. To apply the changed js, css, how do I remove the cache from the past?

Comment: Build files should have different names when you do the changes. So browser won't load cached files. But users do need to refresh the page.

Comment: @ljubadr Yes, the name of the file is changed, but there are times when landering with the old cache on the browser. Is there a more certain way?

Comment: I have the same problem. The "html" page returned by nuxt server-side-renderig is cached. I use apache to proxy my traffic to the nuxt server. Not sure if this is an Apache or Nust issue. Did you solve the problem meanwhile?

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/4764#issuecomment-713469389
Implementation of this one:

> Add a plugin filename **route.client.js** 
> Include in **nuxt.config.json**

```
function getClientAppVersion() {
  return localStorage.getItem('APP_VERSION') ?? 0
}

function setClientAppVersion(version) {
 return localStorage.setItem('APP_VERSION', version)
}

export default ({ app }) => {
app.router.afterEach((to, from) => {
fetch("/version.json").then((serverPromise) => 
 serverPromise.json().then((response) => {
  const latestVersion = response.version
  const clientStoredVersion = getClientAppVersion()

  if (clientStoredVersion != latestVersion) {
    window.location.reload(true)
    setClientAppVersion(latestVersion)
  }
  else return
 }))
})}
```

> Add **version.jon** file

```
{
 "version": "9.1"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you used **run generate** for the project, then you should go to **dist/index.html** and set version to all script tag source like this:

before:

```
<link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/d88504d.js" as="script">
```

after:

```
<link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/d88504d.js?v=1.1" as="script">
```

but if u used **run build** for your project It gets a little more complicated.
in that case u should go to :

> .nuxt/dist/server

then if your project is **ssr** go to

> `index.ssr.html`

and if your project is **spa** go to

> index.spa.html

then you should change script source version like this:

before:

```
<script src="/_nuxt/9df4ed5.js"></script>
```

after:

```
<script src="/_nuxt/9df4ed5.js?v=1.1"></script>
```

ps:
v=1.1 is a random number. you can use whatever you want ! And after any **run build** or **generate** u should change this number for forcing the browser to reload the scripts.